# Is there any way to autoscale data with zeros using scale() in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, scale

I have dataframe with zeros values. I want to autoscale it to do the HCA. When I tried to use scale() method i get:

*Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric*

I tried to delete/change names of rows and columns to numbers but I think the problem is in the zeros.

When I check dataframe with is.numeric() method it gets FALSE.
How can I deal with zeros in my data? Maybe there is another solution to autoscale the data? Maybe I should delete rows/columns containing zeros?

dataframe with data I want to scale
[image]

```
> str(data_to_scale)
'data.frame':   28 obs. of  26 variables:
 $ Self.harm                              : chr  " 4426465" "    6927" "    1255" "   27168" ...
 $ Interpersonal_violence                 : chr  "1573032" "   3846" "    682" "  16478" ...
 $ Drowning                               : chr  "1024514" "   1170" "    304" "   6141" ...
 $ Malaria                                : chr  " 567815" "      0" "      0" "   2336" ...
 $ Fire_heat_hot_substances               : chr  " 394624" "    615" "    118" "   3043" ...
 $ Neoplasms                              : chr  " 8979067" "   17773" "    2999" "   66942" ...
 $ Digestive_diseases                     : chr  " 4087605" "    5897" "    1254" "   36807" ...
 $ Cirrhosis_other_chronic_liver_diseases : chr  " 3026877" "    3795" "     852" "   22382" ...
 $ Chronic_respiratory_diseases           : chr  "1470757" "   1604" "    429" "  11105" ...
 $ Chronic_kidney_disease                 : chr  "1354197" "   1524" "    324" "  10460" ...
 $ Cardiovascular_diseases                : chr  "10203636" "   17218" "    3738" "   81934" ...
 $ Drug_use_disorders                     : chr  " 622210" "    269" "     55" "   2692" ...
 $ Nutritional_deficiencies               : chr  "310873" "    90" "    16" "  1694" ...
 $ Alcohol_use_disorders                  : chr  " 645510" "    665" "     89" "   3673" ...
 $ Lower_respiratory_infections           : chr  "1145551" "   2583" "    466" "  19002" ...
 $ Diabetes_mellitus                      : chr  " 681255" "   1511" "    395" "   7712" ...
 $ Protein.energy_malnutrition            : chr  "174726" "    60" "     0" "  1327" ...
 $ Exposure_to_forces_of_nature           : chr  "165359" "    34" "     6" "   421" ...
 $ Environmental_heat_and_cold_exposure   : chr  "173746" "    93" "    21" "  1028" ...
 $ Diarrheal_diseases                     : chr  "1991449" "    159" "     29" "   4603" ...
 $ Road_injuries                          : chr  " 5060487" "    9976" "    1885" "   49710" ...
 $ Tuberculosis                           : chr  " 4857250" "    1008" "     137" "   22231" ...
 $ HIV.AIDS                               : chr  " 5740628" "    1476" "     202" "   38079" ...
 $ Alzheimer.s_disease_and_other_dementias: chr  "25249" "   60" "    0" "  215" ...
 $ Parkinson.s_disease                    : chr  "19178" "   30" "    0" "  106" ...
 $ Acute_hepatitis                        : chr  " 246523" "     82" "     11" "   1398" ...
```

Comment: Can you post the `str` of your data frame? Also, which variable are you scaling to mean?

Comment: chr means that the values are all character in the column. you need to convert each variable into numeric first before running scale.

Comment: How are you importing the data?

Comment: I edit my post to show you a str of data frame. I want to scale every variable.

Comment: @TechCommodities I import it from excel using read_excel() from readxl package

Comment: Your data needs to be numeric for the scaling to work.  So, two options - 1) Convert the characters in numerics, using `as.numeric()`.  Try 'colMean(as.numeric(x), na.rm = TRUE)'.  A long shot, but may work.

Comment: 2) Read in the data as numbers.  read_excel() guesses data type, but instead, specify that the data is numbers, `read_excel("yo.xlsx", col_types = "numeric")` and see what comes in.

Comment: @TechCommodities quite likely the values were formatted as character on the excel input in the first place.

Comment: @mjrmc you may want to use `dplyr::mutate_all` to convert your data as numeric. Try this: `scale(mutate_all(data_to_scale, as.numeric))`.

Comment: @TechCommodities I used the last method you suggested. I lost information about Country importing that way: 
`read_excel("yo.xlsx", col_types = "numeric")`
Thank you very much